# why my codes in countdown turns negative

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

```
function ShowTime() {
  var now = new Date();
  var hrs = 19-now.getHours();
  var mins = 60-now.getMinutes();
  var secs = 60-now.getSeconds();
      timeLeft = "&nbsp;&nbsp;" +hrs+'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; '+mins+' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; '+secs+' ';
  $("#countdown").html(timeLeft);
}

var countdown;
function StopTime() {
    clearInterval(countdown);

}

setInterval(ShowTime ,1000);
```

8:30pm here. and i want if he got the 9pm, the countdown restart again, it restart every 9pm.. and it goes negative..

Comment: `19-now.getHours()`, if your hours are above 19 that'll be negative

Comment: And where is the call to `StopTime`?

Comment: Also, your clearing of the countdown won't work as it isn't assigned (aka `stopTime` will do _nothing_ since `countdown` was never set to an interval).

Comment: This should go without saying, but there are 24 hours in a day. If it's 8:30 PM where you are, then the value of `now.getHours()` would be 20, would it not?

Comment: if i set 24, the countdown restart in 12am, but my system wants 9pm, any other solutions to this?

Comment: `var hours = now.getHours() - 9; hours = hours < 0 ? 24 + hours : hours`? Something like that. To be honest, thought, it might be better to actually just work with an average.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw lol, thanks!  i didnt notice that! thankyou! sorry for this. this is a mess. i will delete this. thankyou everyone for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function ShowTime() {
  var now = new Date();
var hrs;
var currentHours = now.getHours();
if(currentHours>19){
hrs = 24-currentHours+19;
}else{
  hrs = 19-now.getHours();
}
  var mins = 60-now.getMinutes();
  var secs = 60-now.getSeconds();
      timeLeft = "&nbsp;&nbsp;" +hrs+'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; '+mins+' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; '+secs+' ';
  $("#countdown").html(timeLeft);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign `countdown` value if you wan to use `clearInterval`:

```
countdown = setInterval(ShowTime ,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make the logic like this.

```
If now >19 then
timeLeft is (24-now)+19
else hrs = 19-now;
```